# Recharts Customized X Axis

Tags: recharts

Does anyone know if the below scenario with the weeks axis is possible in recharts?

Let's say for example, there is a days graph. There are about 20 consecutive days in the X Axis. You need an additional X Axis below that mentions the week #, but the week should float in the middle of the range of it's associated days, like below:

```
    Mon Tue Wed Thr Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thr Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thr Fri Sat

               Week 1                      Week 2                   Week 3
```

Edit: I think this is possible if we create a custom function for the axis and add a couple of conditions for the placement of the week# to be precisely under a certain area.

Thank you for the comments and research! My requirements have changed so I did not go further into this issue.

Answer (score 11):

**It's absolutely possible to have many XAxis on your graph.** For this, you need to add an `<XAxis />` line to your graph, and set its `xAxisId` to a unique value, so that the graph can differentiate the different XAxis. (NB: all XAxis will need a different xAxisId; its default value being set to `0`, you'll need to override this default value).

Then, to have a general XAxis data without any repetitions, you'll need the `allowDuplicatedCategory` prop on the XAxis set to `false`. However, the first and last tick will not be centered. I'll see if I can find a solution for this.

With your given data example, the resulted graph could look like this:

```js
import React from "react";

import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "recharts";

const data = [
  { name: "Mon", uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400, week: "Week 1" },
  { name: "Tue", uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210, week: "Week 1" },
  { name: "Wed", uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290, week: "Week 1" },
  { name: "Thu", uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000, week: "Week 1" },
  { name: "Fri", uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181, week: "Week 1" },
  { name: "Sat", uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500, week: "Week 1" },
  { name: "Sun", uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100, week: "Week 1" },
  ...
];

const SimpleLineChart = () => {
  return (
    <LineChart
      width={1200}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
    >
      <XAxis xAxisId="0" dataKey="name" />
      <XAxis xAxisId="1" dataKey="week" allowDuplicatedCategory={false} />
      <YAxis />
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="pv"
        stroke="#8884d8"
        activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
      />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
    </LineChart>
  );
};

export default SimpleLineChart;
```

[image]