# Display a button in X axis with recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have to create a bar chart using recharts. In the X axis I need to display the label **and a button** linked to each particular bar in order to do an action.

I found that [it is possible to use more than a single X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210970/13672532) but I don't seem to find how to replace the dataKey to a component instead of a string. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found information in recharts API https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedLabelLineChart

It is possible to create a react component as long as it returns a  element, and since it's possible to add an onClick function it can behave as a button. Here's the example:

```
class CustomizedAxisTick extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { x, y, stroke, payload } = this.props;

    return (
      <g transform={`translate(${x},${y})`} onClick={()=> console.log(payload.value)}>
        <text x={0} y={0} dy={16} textAnchor="end" fill="#666" transform="rotate(-35)">
          {payload.value}
        </text>
      </g>
    );
  }
}
```

then you just need to call the component in the XAxis like this:

```
<XAxis tick={<CustomizedTick />} />
```